# jquery css using arrays as values

Tags: jquery, css, arrays

I am creating a function that I need to pass in values from an array, one of the values I need to add in is a series of values for the jquery css array

essentially I need to do the following

```
myArray = new Array();
myArray[0] = ""{'float':'left','-webkit-border-top-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-top-right-radius':'0px','-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius':'20px'}";"
function(){
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
$(this).css(myArray[0]):
});
}
```

That's not the exact code as its part of a way bigger function, however the aspect I am falling down on is passing the string in the array to the .css array, I can do this if I were to only include the value in the array, however this means I need to add additional items to my array which I don't want to do

Any help - pointers would be appreciated

### Many thanks!

So for context

okay so my array is 
`var card2Pos = new Array();
    card2Pos[0]="475px";
    card2Pos[1]="80px";
    card2Pos[2]="1";
    card2Pos[3]="500px";
    card2Pos[4]="70px";
    card2Pos[5]="90px";
    card2Pos[6]="510px";
    card2Pos[7]="9";

    card2Pos[8]="{'float':'left','-webkit-border-top-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-top-right-radius':'0px','-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius':'20px'}";
    card2Pos[9]="475px";
    card2Pos[10]="80px";
    card2Pos[11]="580px";
    card2Pos[12]="60px";
    card2Pos[13]="8";
    card2Pos[14]="right";
    card2Pos[15]="450px";
    card2Pos[16]="90px";
    card2Pos[17]="625px";
    card2Pos[18]="60px";
    card2Pos[19]="7";
    card2Pos[20]="right";
    card2Pos[21]="425px";
    card2Pos[22]="100px";
    card2Pos[23]="670px";
    card2Pos[24]="60px";
    card2Pos[25]="6";
    card2Pos[26]="right";
    card2Pos[27]="400px";
    card2Pos[28]="110px";
    card2Pos[29]="715px";
    card2Pos[30]="60px";
    card2Pos[31]="5";
    card2Pos[32]="right";
    card2Pos[33]="375px";
    card2Pos[34]="120px";
    card2Pos[35]="760px";
    card2Pos[36]="60px";
    card2Pos[37]="4";
    card2Pos[38]="right";
    card2Pos[39]="350px";
    card2Pos[40]="130px";
    card2Pos[41]="805px";
    card2Pos[42]="60px";
    card2Pos[43]="3";
    card2Pos[44]="right";
    card2Pos[45]="325px";
    card2Pos[46]="140px";
    card2Pos[47]="850px";
    card2Pos[48]="60px";
    card2Pos[49]="2";
    card2Pos[50]="right";`
being passed into the following function 
`
    function uber(arg) {
        $card1.animate({
                        height:arg[0],
                        top:arg[1]
                        },500).css({'z-index':card2Pos[2]});

```
    $card2.animate({
                    height:arg[3],
                    top:arg[4],
                    left:arg[5],
                    width:arg[6]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[7]});
    $card2Nav.css(arg[8]);
    $card3.animate({
                    height:arg[9],
                    top:arg[10],
                    left:arg[11],
                    width:arg[12]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[13]});
    $card3Nav.css({'float':arg[14]});
    $card4.animate({
                    height:arg[15],
                    top:arg[16],
                    left:arg[17],
                    width:arg[18]                       
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[19]});
    $card4Nav.css({'float':arg[20]});
    $card5.animate({
                    height:arg[21],
                    top:arg[22],
                    left:arg[23],
                    width:arg[24]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[25]});
    $card5Nav.css({'float':arg[26]});
    $card6.animate({
                    height:arg[27],
                    top:arg[28],
                    left:arg[29],
                    width:arg[30]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[31]});
    $card6Nav.css({'float':arg[32]});
    $card7.animate({
                    height:arg[33],
                    top:arg[34],
                    left:arg[35],
                    width:arg[36]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[37]});
    $card7Nav.css({'float':arg[38]});
    $card8.animate({
                    height:arg[39],
                    top:arg[40],
                    left:arg[41],
                    width:arg[42]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[43]});
    $card8Nav.css({'float':arg[44]});
    $card9.animate({
                    height:arg[45],
                    top:arg[46],
                    left:arg[47],
                    width:arg[48]
                    },500).css({'z-index':arg[49]});
    $card9Nav.css({'float':arg[50]});
}
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, but don't store it as a string - rather directly as an object, like this:

```
var myArray = [
  {'float':'left','-webkit-border-top-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-top-right-radius':'0px','-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius':'20px'}
  //more objects...
];
$(function(){
  $("#myDiv").click(function(){
    $(this).css(myArray[0]);
  });
});
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RfzXb/1/).

Comment: Ah  thanks, but thats not going to serve the purpose unfortunately, the aim is to have 1 function that takes the array name as its argument, this has lots of other properties inside it so I ideally need it to be all in one array :(

Comment: @user499846 - this uses a single array...I'm not following, can you clarify? It sounds like you want an object rather than an array if you want named access.

Comment: Sure, sorry that was probably not the best description! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at this first:
[jQuery Array tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Than I think that it can work perfectly, just passing the code in a more clear way:

```
var myArray = new Array(1);
myArray[0] = "{ float:'left', -webkit-border-top-left-radius:'20px', etc...}";

$("#myDiv").click(function(){
$(this).css(myArray[0]): //this put the css on #myDiv
});
```

Comment: @Torro
Thanks for the link and the code, however the code doesn't work :/ even after the replacing the ':' with a ';' on the end of your second from last line

I added the following code as a test and it failed with no errors

Comment: `<script src="script/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<style>
div { border: solid 1px #ddd; width:800px;height:800px;background:red; }
</style>
<div id="myDiv">Click me!</div>

<script>
var myArray = new Array(1);
myArray[0] = "{ float:'left', -webkit-border-top-left-radius:'20px', height:'10px'}";



$("#myDiv").click(function(){
 alert('clicked')
 $(this).css(myArray[0]); //this put the css on #myDiv
});
</script>`

Comment: is strange, I tryed right now and it works.. (safari, ff and ie8).

Comment: Now I see if there is some improvement to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

$(this).css({
    width: '100%', 
    height: '600px'
});

Comment: In what way it is different from @Nick-Craver answer?

Answer (score 0):

hi the discussion is really help full for me for the same case. The following may be the solution you are looking for.

```
var myArray ={'float':'right','font-size':'24px','-webkit-border-top-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius':'20px','-webkit-border-top-right-radius':'0px','-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius':'20px'};
$(function(){
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
$(this).css(myArray);
});
});
```